# How to make UITabBar change content in one viewcontroller instead change to other viewcontroller ?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I want to make an UITabBar like in photo editing app that contain frame in bottom, when uiTabBar change the image conten stay still but just change the editor section like in VSCO.

Could you please advice, how to deal with it? thanks in advance!

Comment: How About using a CollectionView ? in selection Update the Frame , customise as Tab Bar

Comment: @iOSGeek thats actually good approach, however i think about make UITabBar, then push my customize view when item selected. But still i need some advice, Thanks for reply :)

Comment: I think tabbar will not be a good approach , suppose you have frames count more than 100 or 20 Tab bar will show more after count is greater than 5 and collectionView will help you in this case, everytime populating a screen not a good approach , Tabbar won't help you much if still tell me how can I help you out

Comment: @iOSGeek https://imgur.com/a/VAn7J how about i make like this ?

Comment: That is exactly I am saying , use collectionView for frame list

Comment: @iOSGeek Thanks, much appreciated :)